# Data being truncated using TZCompressionStream

Tags: delphi, compression

I have the following declarations:

```
stmCompressor: TZCompressionStream;
stmCompressed: TMemoryStream;
stmBlob: TStream;
```

I have the following code:

```
stmBlob := qry.CreateBlobStream(qry.FieldByName(sFieldName), bmRead);
stmCompressed := TMemoryStream.Create;
stmCompressor := TZCompressionStream.Create(stmCompressed); 
stmBlob.Position := 0;
stmCompressor.CopyFrom(stmBlob, stmBlob.Size);
stmCompressed.Position := 0;
stmCompressed.SaveToFile('C:\Temp\CompressedData2.zip');
```

I am trying to compress image data from the database and place the result in the memory stream stmCompressed. I am then saving stmCompressed into a file so that I can check the result. The result appears to be a truncated form of what it should be. If the compressed data is larger than 80000H then the file is truncated to this size. If the data is larger than B0000H then the file is truncated to this size.

The funny thing is that if I change stmCompressed from a TMemoryStream to a TFileStream then it works perfectly (the code is not exactly the same - I can post it if it would help).

I need the result to be in a memory stream, so I would appreciate any help anyone can offer. I'm using the standard ZLib library that comes with XE2.

Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you close the memory stream just before SaveToFile?

Comment: If you want a ZIP file then you should use TZipFile. If you are compressing images, ZIP/zlib may be a poor choice of compressor.

Answer (score 6):

You have to Free the TZCompressionStream to flush the remaining bytes into the memory stream.

Comment: Thanks a lot Uwe, that was the problem.